# Renaming figure caption in proper way

Tags: captions

I would like a following caption for my figures:

```
Figure S1
Figure S2
```

etc. Now, I used

```
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure S}
```

but the issue is that after `S`, there is a whitespace, instead of a number solely, so I get `Figure S 1`. I don't like it. Could you give me a tip how to get rid of this whitespace, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should modify the `\thefigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{ A figure}\label{fig:picture}
  \end{figure}
  \ref{fig:picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand if you want `S` to appear only in the caption and not in the references, define a label format using `caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=mysimple}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mysimple}%
{\bothIfFirst{#1}{~}S#2}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{ A figure}\label{fig:picture}
  \end{figure}
  \ref{fig:picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]